# Better way to ensure rule precedence in CSS?

Tags: css

Let's say I have two CSS classes:

```
.all {
    background-color: red;
    border: 5px solid black;
}

.some {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Some HTML elements will have the attribute `class="all some"` (i.e. they will have both classes). In this case, I want the class `some` to override `all` (the element should appear blue, but still have a 5px black border). What is the most efficient way to do this, without using the `!important` keyword? I have used this for a while, and it works (notice the `[class]` specifier on the `some` rule):

```
.all {
    background-color: red;
    border: 5px solid black;
}

.some[class] {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Is there a special "precedence" character in CSS made for situations like this?

Note: there is no guarantee that `some` will always come after `all` in the stylesheets.

Comment: Try increasing the specificity https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 3):

You can declare styles for elements with multiple classes. Like this

```css
.some {}
.all {}
.some.all {}
```

The way it determines which to use is related to the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), also see [this for more examples](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp)

```css
.all, .some {
    background-color: red;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.all.some {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">All</div>
<div class="some">Some</div>
<div class="all some">All/Some</div>
```

Comment: this would result in redundant styling, which is not as efficient as simply using the `.some[class]` specifier. in your example, i would have to re-define the `background-color` and `border` in the `.some.all` rule, duplicating what rules already exist

Comment: You wouldn't have to duplicate them, see the snippet I added, I changed the `.some[class]` selector to `.all.some` and it is working as expected. Does this mitigate the redundancy issue?

Comment: With this solution, if there were more than one "some" class, like `some_0`, `some_1`, and `some_2`, then I would have to add the name of each one to the `all` definition. In my real-life case, I have actually dozens of "some" classes, which would make using this solution cumbersome. I just need a way to collectively assign a specificity to the "some" classes without modifying the original "all" class.

Answer (score 1):

For a better way than hacking the specificity, you need cascade layers.

You can't raise the precedence of `.some`, but you can lower the precedence of `.all`. Do this:

```css
.some {
    background-color: blue;
}

@layer {
  .all {
    background-color: red;
    border: 5px solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="some all">Hello World</p>
```

Comment: I found a way to increase the specificity of a class. It is also scalable for multiple classes. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: @user3163495 - There's several ways to hack the specificity. The traditional way is to repeat the class name e.g. `.some.some`. My preferred modern way is to use `:is()`, for example `:is(.some, #_._._:not(*))` gives a specificity of (1,2,0) to the rule for elements matching `.some`. But the question already has a way of hacking the specificity and you seemed to be looking for a better (or at least alternative) way.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to increase the specificity of a class without using the `!important` keyword. This technique is also scalable, and can accommodate situations where many classes must override a single "base" class.

```
.all {
    background-color: red;
    border: 5px solid black;
}

/* each extra ":not(\\)" increases the specificity.
   for example, this group has 3x the specificity
   over a single ":not(\\)" group. */
:not(\\):not(\\):not(\\) {
    /* each class must be prefixed with ampersand "&" if
       you intend to apply one of these classes to the
       <html> element. if you don't, then you can omit
       the ampersands. */
    &.some_0 {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    &.some_1 {
        background-color: purple;
    }
    &.some_2 {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial CSS works fine. If an element has multiple classes on it and each class has the same level of specificity, the styles will be applied in the order the class selectors appear in the CSS.

```css
.all {
  background-color: red;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.some {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">Foo</div>
<div class="all some">Bar</div>
<div class="some all">Baz</div>
```